# telegram webhook with heroku

Tags: python, heroku, telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to make a telegram echobot with python. I am hosting my python on heroku.

At first I just used telegrams native API methods with python requests, then I used a library [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot).

I was able to get the regular getUpdate methods (which use long polling - that is heroku periodically makes a request to your telegram bot to get updates) working, but the [webhook is not](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Webhooks).

**I think the problem is that heroku will not give access to ports <1024 and telegram [webhook only pushes notifs to ports 80,88,443 and 8443.](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates)**

Does anyone know how I could make this work

here is my code:

```
import os

import logging
import sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout,level=logging.DEBUG)
log = logging.getLogger('my_application')


from proj.heroku_env_vars import teleg_token,secret_key



import telegram
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

global bot
bot = telegram.Bot(token=TOKEN)


@app.route('/%s'%HOOK, methods=['POST'])
def webhook_handler():
    if request.method == "POST":
        log.info('post from teleg')
        # retrieve the message in JSON and then transform it to Telegram object
        update = telegram.Update.de_json(request.get_json(force=True))

        chat_id = update.message.chat.id

        # Telegram understands UTF-8, so encode text for unicode compatibility
        text = update.message.text.encode('utf-8')

        # repeat the same message back (echo)
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=text)
    else:
        log.info('notpost from teleg')

    return 'ok'


@app.route('/swh', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def set_webhook():
    s = bot.setWebhook('%s/%s'%(URL, HOOK), PORT=8443)
    if s:
        return "webhook setup ok"
    else:
        return "webhook setup failed"


@app.route('/dwh', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete_webhook():
    s = bot.deleteWebhook()
    if s:
        return "webhook deleted ok"
    else:
        return "webhook delete failed"


@app.route('/')
def index():
    log.info('i made this request')
    return 'home page.'
```

=====

### 1. DELETE MY WEBHOOK

```
MacBook-Pro-4:proj aiden$ curl https://mysterious-sands-89012.herokuapp.com/dwh
webhook deleted ok
```

### HEROKU LOG

```
2018-05-07T15:24:46.592749+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/dwh" host=mysterious-sands-89012.herokuapp.com request_id=4aef8faf-555e-4697-8a3d-3eea2861eba2 fwd="23.31.215.245" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=404ms status=200 bytes=178 protocol=https
2018-05-07T15:24:46.586755+00:00 app[web.1]: DEBUG:telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.connectionpool:https://api.telegram.org:443 "POST /bot562713672:AAE8Pt1-UDWyKrtIEJ7_igD2t5Zw1z0LRRo/deleteWebhook HTTP/1.1" 200 61
2018-05-07T15:24:46.587925+00:00 app[web.1]: DEBUG:telegram.bot:True
2018-05-07T15:24:46.588080+00:00 app[web.1]: DEBUG:telegram.bot:Exiting: delete_webhook
2018-05-07T15:24:46.589420+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.101.133.97 - - [07/May/2018:15:24:46 +0000] "GET /dwh HTTP/1.1" 200 18 "-" "curl/7.54.0"
```

=============

### 2. SET IT UP AGAIN (specifying port 8443)

```
MacBook-Pro-4:proj aiden$ curl https://mysterious-sands-89012.herokuapp.com/swh
webhook setup ok
```

### HEROKU LOG

```
2018-05-07T15:24:52.194779+00:00 app[web.1]: DEBUG:telegram.bot:Entering: set_webhook
2018-05-07T15:24:52.195462+00:00 app[web.1]: DEBUG:telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.telegram.org
2018-05-07T15:24:52.596829+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/swh" host=mysterious-sands-89012.herokuapp.com request_id=c2cfa1d8-48c2-4abf-a198-cfa8499e9676 fwd="23.31.215.245" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=404ms status=200 bytes=176 protocol=https
2018-05-07T15:24:52.593031+00:00 app[web.1]: DEBUG:telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.connectionpool:https://api.telegram.org:443 "POST /bot562713672:AAE8Pt1-UDWyKrtIEJ7_igD2t5Zw1z0LRRo/setWebhook HTTP/1.1" 200 57
2018-05-07T15:24:52.594936+00:00 app[web.1]: DEBUG:telegram.bot:True
2018-05-07T15:24:52.595055+00:00 app[web.1]: DEBUG:telegram.bot:Exiting: set_webhook
2018-05-07T15:24:52.596418+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.141.252.172 - - [07/May/2018:15:24:52 +0000] "GET /swh HTTP/1.1" 200 16 "-" "curl/7.54.0"
```

=============

### 3. NOW TRY AND POST TO THAT URL (without specifying port)

```
MacBook-Pro-4:p-d "param1=value1&param2=value2" -X POST https://mysterious-sands-89012.herokuapp.com/562713672:AAE8Pt1-UDWyKrtIEJ7_igD2t5Zw1z0LRRo
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)</p>
```

### HEROKU LOG

```
2018-05-07T15:25:05.454666+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO:my_application:post from teleg
2018-05-07T15:25:05.519859+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.101.219.132 - - [07/May/2018:15:25:05 +0000] "POST /562713672:AAE8Pt1-UDWyKrtIEJ7_igD2t5Zw1z0LRRo HTTP/1.1" 400 187 "-" "curl/7.54.0"
2018-05-07T15:25:05.524749+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/562713672:AAE8Pt1-UDWyKrtIEJ7_igD2t5Zw1z0LRRo" host=mysterious-sands-89012.herokuapp.com request_id=3b9713a3-b3db-4db2-8915-29f995560ec2 fwd="23.31.215.245" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=68ms status=400 bytes=342 protocol=https
```

===============

### 4. NOW TRY AND POST TO THAT URL (specifying port)

```
MacBook-Pro-4:proj aiden$ curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" -X POST https://mysterious-sands-89012.herokuapp.com/562713672:AAE8Pt1-UDWyKrtIEJ7_igD2t5Zw1z0LRRo:8443
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

### HEROKU LOG

```
2018-05-07T15:25:14.809828+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/562713672:AAE8Pt1-UDWyKrtIEJ7_igD2t5Zw1z0LRRo:8443" host=mysterious-sands-89012.herokuapp.com request_id=458c911e-62ae-4eee-9cfd-b5a1345e5064 fwd="23.31.215.245" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=386 protocol=https
2018-05-07T15:25:14.804975+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.180.49.12 - - [07/May/2018:15:25:14 +0000] "POST /562713672:AAE8Pt1-UDWyKrtIEJ7_igD2t5Zw1z0LRRo:8443 HTTP/1.1" 404 233 "-" "curl/7.54.0"
```

=================

### 5. AND IF I POST A MESSAGE TO MY TELEGRAM BOT, **NOTHING** SHOWS UP ON MY HEROKU LOGS

Comment: Where is Telegram error message?

Comment: Adding error/log messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `aidentmchugh.pythonanywhere.com` as URL, not include `www`.

Your HTTPS cert didn't signed for `www` domain.

[image: Firefox]

Comment: BTW, it's obtained from your bot token, you have better to revoke that.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll delete the bot or reset the token